# Seeing all columns of a correlation matrix in Spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pearson-correlation

I am trying to train a k-means model and currently in phase of checking correlation within my feature vectors.

When I run a pearson correlation against my feature vector I am unable to see results for all of my features.

The code I am running is:

```
val cor = Correlation.corr(scoringDf, "features")
cor.show(false)
```

The correlation runs fine but when i try to see the results using show method (as Correlation.corr returns a Datafame object) the results are displayed as

```
|1.0                  0.18047211468479446  0.08002566273874058   ... (5 total)
0.18047211468479446  1.0                  0.02926796076983553   ...
0.08002566273874058  0.02926796076983553  1.0                   ...
0.30256416877032244  0.15974389490583188  0.054692657400425136  ...
0.3408783412055776   0.13008391583866225  0.04241296238931376   ...|
```

Is there a way to see the hidden columns?

I have also tried the following code but results are same.

```
val Row(coeff1: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(scoringDf, "features").head
println(s"Pearson correlation matrix:\n $coeff1")
```

Edit:

here is the schema for cor dataframe

```
root
 |-- pearson(features): matrix (nullable = false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to get the output the way I want.
Changed my code to look like this

```
val Row(coeff1: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(scoringDf, "features").head
println(s"Pearson correlation matrix:\n " + coeff1.toString(10, 100000))
```

The output is displayed as shown below:

```
Pearson correlation matrix:
 1.0                  0.1804721146847944   0.08002566273874055   0.3025641687703226   0.34087834120557725   
0.1804721146847944   1.0                  0.02926796076983553   0.15974389490583193  0.13008391583866233   
0.08002566273874055  0.02926796076983553  1.0                   0.05469265740042514  0.042412962389313726  
0.3025641687703226   0.15974389490583193  0.05469265740042514   1.0                  0.241118490251708     
0.34087834120557725  0.13008391583866233  0.042412962389313726  0.241118490251708    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

method show() has several options, for example you can try:

```
def show(numRows: Int, truncate: Int, vertical: Boolean): Unit
```

numRows
Number of rows to show

truncate
If set to more than 0, truncates strings to truncate characters and all cells will be aligned right.

vertical
If set to true, prints output rows vertically (one line per column value).

You can see the documentation.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

I hope, it can be helpful.

Regards.

Comment: it didnt help, even after using the above defination, i get similar output

Comment: I changed my answer, maybe it can help.

Comment: By the way, are you using the spark-shell, spark-submit, IntelliJ or Eclipse?

Comment: i am using Jupyter notebook. Btw I just edited my question with the schema of a cor dataframe. I suspect its the Matrix type which is not allowing all fields to be shown

Comment: I found the answer to my problem.